# Enable access to images only for specific user

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I'm working on asp.net site and I want to give access to folders only when user need the images from this folder. for example: if user want this specific image: www.xyz.com/a/1.jpg He could not get access directly from url unless the web page he visit present this image. Now i'm using Base64 encoding but it is downloading the image slowly. Threre is another solution? I was thinking about copy the image to public folder and give access to the image from that folder - if the user is browsing www.xyz.com/a.aspx and on a.aspx there is dynamicly image that change from user to user(like profile pic), the image would copy to another folder and the user would get the copy of the image url.
What do you think? there is simple solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the Base64 is causing delays? Base64 is really simple to decode (read:quick), so I'm not sure if that is the cause.

Comment: @MrLister The decode itself do not take long time, the downloading of huge base64 image taking too long. the problem is when you downloading normal image, the browser keep downloading other things at the same time. when you download b64 image from asp.net server, it waiting until the line that write the b64 image to the image element and only when finish - the browser keep downloading another things.. what makes thing slow..